Dynamically Load Data in Power BI
I want to dynamically load some data into Power BI so that updates in the database are reflected on it without the need to republish it.
Is there a way to run a new query every time you select an item in a dropdown menu?

Thanks for your response, but it did not solve my problem. It indeed allows you to connect directly to a database and run queries on it. However, it cannot run a custom dynamic query based on a dropdown menu selection. In my specific case, I need to run a predefined stored procedure with different parameters based on the dropdown menu selection.
